# Connect to ActiveMQ broker using STOMP from Ionic App

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, stomp, sockjs

I have been given an Ionic + Capacitor app which will mainly be compiled to run on the Android platform. I've been tasked with integrating communication with a remote ActiveMQ broker into the app. I used the STOMP JS library to achieve this and works really well when I test it on the browser. Now, when I test this on the emulator, the application fails to connect to the ActiveMQ broker. I belive this is because the browser supports WebSockets out-of-the-box, while the emulator can't understand the WS URL. I read online that I could use SockJS as an easy fix for this, and can be integrated quite easily into my current code. I'm referring to the below tutorial:

https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/stompjs/rx-stomp/ng2-stompjs/using-stomp-with-sockjs.html

However, when I follow the instructions and add the fallback code provided in the tutorial, I get a weired error that the Typescript compiler throws. My code is below:

```
import {Client, Message, ActivationState, messageCallbackType} from '@stomp/stompjs'
//import StompJs, { Message } from '@stomp/stompjs';
import { Queue } from 'queue-typescript';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

const brokerEndpoint = "ws://localhost:61614";
//const brokerEndpoint = "ws://10.0.2.2:61614";

const items: string[] = [];
const queue = new Queue<string>(...items);

const createClient = () => {
    const client: Client = new Client({
        brokerURL: brokerEndpoint,
        connectHeaders: {
            login: 'admin',
            passcode: 'admin',
        },
        debug: function (str) {
            console.log(str);
        },
        reconnectDelay: 1000,
        heartbeatIncoming: 0,
        heartbeatOutgoing: 0
    });

    client.webSocketFactory = new SockJS('http://localhost:61613/stomp');

    /*
    if (typeof WebSocket !== 'function') {
        console.log("Not WebScoket");
        // For SockJS you need to set a factory that creates a new SockJS instance
        // to be used for each (re)connect
        client.webSocketFactory = function () {
            // Note that the URL is different from the WebSocket URL
            return new SockJS('http://10.0.2.2:15674/stomp');
        };
    } else {
        console.log("Still using websockets");
    }
    */

    return client;
}

const client: Client = createClient()
```

The line below is where the error is thrown:

```
client.webSocketFactory = new SockJS('http://localhost:61613/stomp');
```

The compiler says that "Type 'WebSocket' is not assignable to type '() => IStompSocket'.
Type 'WebSocket' provides no match for the signature '(): IStompSocket'."

According to the tutorial, it seems that I've done the right thing. However, Typescript seems to think that there exists some incompatibility. Has anybody worked with SockJS + STOMP or with any of the libraries that I've imported, and got it to work successfully? Any leads will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Do you use Angular for your Ionic project? Do you use Angular implementation of `stomp-js` (`@stomp/ng2-stompjs`)?

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko: Actually this app uses Vue, not Angular. I'm guessing the same library can't be used for this purpose? And, I'm using the normal implementation of stompjs [link] (https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs). In fact, I'm open to using other protocols to connect to ActiveMQ. It's just that from my research, STOMP made the most sense

Comment: Hm... I'm not familiar with vue. Did you check this: https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/stompjs/rx-stomp/ng2-stompjs/pollyfils-for-stompjs-v5.html ?

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko: Yes I did. However, since my browser support Websockets, I'm not sure if it applies to me. It's just when this Ionic app is compiled for the Android platform, it doesn't work since it can't understand the WS URL. SockJS seemed to be the fix for it. However, I'm not able to connect to the broker using SockJS. Do you have any experience with SockJS, or any other similar libraries? I'm willing to change my entire approach as well. Just need to be able to connect from my Ionic ap to the ActiveMQ broker (from Android and browser).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SockJS` but I think your problem is related to missing type definition or some global settings. Can you try to find a place where is a problem arises? Also, you can try to convert type to needed type manually.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same error as yours, the problem is the version of the npm dependency @stomp/stompjs.

As i've investigated, it seems the guy that made it wanted to do some changes, but ended up doing a mess, even so that he didn't even care to update the official documentation.

In the official webpage it still shows that the method webSocketFactory returns a WebSocket interface, when in reality, it returns IStompSocket, which is "supposed" to be the same as WebSocket interface, but it isn't, and there is no documented way to transform a WebSocket to IStompSocket. That's why it fails.

**here is the fix:**

**1º uninstall the current version, type:**

npm uninstall @stomp/stompjs

**2º install the same dependency with this version:**

npm install @stomp/stompjs@5.2.0 --save

I really hope it works.